# Customizing SharePoint 2010 Survey

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, survey

I have this Customer Satisfaction Survey with 3 questions. Users want a modification that whenever a question is answered, instead of clicking next button for the subsequent question, the question will appear below on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the custom list template instead of the Survey. The Survey is, yes, designed for this purpose. However, the NewForm that is generated for Surveys gives the Next/Back buttons that show one question at a time. I would create a new Custom List, and recreate all the questions as columns in that list. The New Item form will generated question by question in order on the same page.